# Верно ли что нужно начинать отрисовывать сначала те меши, которые находятся дальше всех от камеры? Direct3D 11

Tags: c++, directx

Особенное, если нужно нарисовать прозрачные объекты?

Comment: Я, конечно, не специалист, но мне кажется, что понятие «дальше всех» может быть и некорректным. Например, в букве Х которая из «палок» ближе к низу?

Comment: Сложный вопрос и лень тут что-то писать. Почитайте что-нибудь про [Z буфер](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering), [BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) и [LOD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_Detail). В принципе то или иное комбинирование этих способов так или иначе на практике решает эту проблему.

Comment: В идеале лучше вообще не рисовать то что не видно.

Comment: Для того чтобы получить быстродействие за счет исключения перирисовки одних и тех же фрагментов, надо рисовать от ближних к дальним. Тогда с высокой вероятностью 1 пиксель экрана будет нарисован 1 раз (при использовании Z буфера) -> 1 раз будет вызван пиксель шейдер, и уменьшится нагрузка на GPU. Понятное дело это имеет смысл если в сцене много перекрывающихся объектов. Например, у вас вид от первого лица в шутере и вы смотрите на город/лес. При рисовании полупрозрачных мешей через альфа-бленд, сортировка должна быть от дальних к ближним (пикселей) так как формула для блендинга некоммутативна.

Comment: @outcast Можете оформить комментарий как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы увеличить быстродействие за счет исключения перерисовки одних и тех же фрагментов, надо рисовать от ближних к дальним. Тогда с высокой вероятностью один пиксель (фрагмент) на экране будет нарисован один раз (при включенном Z буфере). И соответственно, один раз будет вызван пиксель шейдер, и уменьшится нагрузка на GPU. Это имеет смысл если в сцене много перекрывающихся объектов. Например, вид от первого лица в шутере и вы смотрите на город/лес.

При рисовании полупрозрачных мешей через альфа-бленд, сортировка должна быть от дальних к ближним (пикселей) так как формула для смешения при полупрозрачности  некоммутативна:
c = ( a * src ) + ( 1 - a ) * dst, где src рисуемый пиксель, а dst значение в буфере кадра, a - величина непрозрачности (альфа) от src.

Из этого правила есть одно исключение, когда используется аддитивный блендинг, например для огня и вспышек (и других объектов с самосвечением) - можно рисовать без сортировки, так как формула будет:
c = ( a * src ) + dst

Попиксельная сортировка относительно медленная, требует современных GPU, и обладает некоторыми сложностями в реализации. Поэтому на практике сортируют на уровне объектов (или по треугольникам в крайнем случае). В этом случае, от полупрозрачных объектов требуется быть выпуклыми, и по возможности не пересекаться в пространстве (в большинстве случаев это достижимо, усилиями артистов и дизайнеров при минимальном вмешательстве программистов). От программиста требуется только отсортировать видимые полупрозрачные объекты по удаленности от камеры, а затем нарисовать их задние/передние грани в порядке от дальних к ближним. Запись в Z буфер должна быть отключена, а проверка на Z включена. В случае выпуклых взаимно непересекающихся объектов это гарантирует правильный порядок отрисовки пикселей.

Полупрозрачные объекты стоит рисовать в самом конце чтобы, по возможности отрисованные ранее непрозрачные закрыли как можно больше пикселей полупрозрачных.